# How to use nltk stopwords and stemming in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk, tf-idf

For a simple web classifier I am trying to remove stop words from my text and apply stemming before using tfidf. I know that tfidf in scikit offers the possibility to remove stop words, but I thought I could as well do it beforehand using nltk.

After cleaning the raw html code with beautifulsoup and removing \n characters with regex, I ended up with what seemed to me a fairly clean text. When I try to apply stopwords, however, I end up with complete gibberish:

> [u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u'n', u' ', u'n', u' ', u'c', u'p', u'u',
>   u'n', u' ', u'n', u' ', u'p', u'g', u'e', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ',
>   u'n', u' ', u'n', u' ', u'c', u'p', u'u', u'n', u' ', u'n', u' ',
>   u'p', u'g', u'e', u' ', u'c', u'6']

and it continues like that for a long time in every cell.

The code I have been using (in Jupyter notebook) is the following:

```
    import os 
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re

    def readData (path):
        data = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=["label", "raw_html", "soup", "raw_text"])
        i = 0
        for cat in os.listdir(path):
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,cat)):
                for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(path,cat)):
                    content = get_rid_of_mime(path, cat, file)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
                    raw_text = re.sub(r'\n', ' ', soup.getText())
                    data.loc[i] = [cat, content, soup, raw_text]
                    i = i+1
        return data

def get_rid_of_mime(path, cat, file):
    html = False
    content = ""
    with open(os.path.join(path, cat, file)) as input:
        for line in input:
            if (html or re.match("^\s*<",line)):
                content += line
                html = True
    return (content.lower())

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words("english")

train_data["raw_text"] = train_data["raw_text"].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
```

Furthermore, it would be nice to have this text excl. stopwords as a new column in the dataframe instead of replacing the raw_text with it. I tried this with

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words("english")

for index, row in train_data.iterrows():
    text = row["raw_text"]

    train_data.loc[index, 'text_excl_stop'] = text.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
```

but that resulted in

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'apply'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I tried to use .split(' ') as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words("english")

train_data["raw_text"] = train_data["raw_text"].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x.split(' ') if item not in stop])
```

which resulted in a slightly better, more expected output:

> [u'', u'', u'', u'', u'mind', u'computation', u'main', u'page', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'mind', u'computation', u'main', u'page', u'c690:',
>   u'mind', u'computation,', u'1995-6', u'', u'', u'', u'mind',
>   u'computation', u'seminar', u'features', u'talks', u'iu', u'graduate',
>   u'students', u'faculty', u'occasional'] (etc)

although this is still not yet as would be expected...

[Output before stopwords with nltk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plW1f.png)
[Output after stopwords with nltk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psIel.png)

Comment: I think that's too many questions. As to the error, you seem to be using "apply" on something that's neither a DataFrame nor a Series, but a "unicode" object (try type(text)). You are also obviously getting unicode strings (your "gibberish" is in fact unicode strings) but that may be a good thing, depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Try `train_data["raw_text"] = train_data["raw_text"].str.replace(r"\s*\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(stop)), "")`